# Trying to upgrade MariaDB server

Tags: upgrade, mariadb

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04trusty with MariaDB server 5.5.41 and would like to upgrade to version 10.

I shutdown and uninstalled 5.5.41 per instructions, ran the updates, and apt-get and got the following:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.0
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/6,000 kB of archives.
After this operation, 78.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server-10.0.
(Reading database ... 55701 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.17+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.17+maria-1~trusty) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server_10.0.17+maria-1~trusty_all.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server (10.0.17+maria-1~trusty) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.17+maria-1~trusty) ...
mysql start/running, process 4592
Setting up mariadb-server (10.0.17+maria-1~trusty) …
```

Did a reboot, logged back into phpmyadmin - and it still says I'm running version 5.5.41 - even though that version was removed.

This is supposed to be a no-brainer - and I qualify for that! But I can't figure out what's going on here.

Can anybody tell me? Or point me to the instructions that were written for people likem me? ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm….may have been a caching issue since I logged back in to phpmyadmin 30 minutes later and it's now showing the server version as 10.0.17!